# How edit EvenData message in Receiver Event Hub?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm a beginner and I have a problem. I can not replace the individual message in my receiver event hub. Does anyone know a way how I can fix this?

```
 public Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
    {


            try
        {
            foreach (EventData message in messages)
            {
                    string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.GetBytes());
                    NewClient Client = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewClient>(data);
                    GPSApi Gpsobject = new GPSApi();
                    Gpsobject.GetJson(Client.City, Client.Street);
                    Gpsobject.DeserializeJson();
                    Gpsobject.ConvertJson();
                    WeatherApi WeatherApiobject = new WeatherApi();
                    WeatherApiobject.GetJson(Gpsobject.convertlat, Gpsobject.convertlng);
                    data = WeatherApiobject.sendEvent;
                    EventData data1 = new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
                    //message = data1;
                // LUB TUTAJ                    
                Interlocked.Increment(ref this.totalMessages);
                this.LastMessageOffset = data1.Offset;
            }
```

I've tried loop. e.g.

```
(int i=0; i<messages.Count(); i++)
```

Also not working.

Comment: By considering your messages are in json format; you can deserialize your message in json list and then loop through each message.

Comment: I am not really sure what it is you are trying to accomplish. You want to alter the messages in the loop? And then what? For what purpose?

Comment: DSA, can you show me how do this on example?

Comment: Peter Bons- 
I would after receiving customer data in the message, then download it to the weather, and replace the message of the weather, which continue to be sent to the stream analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would after receiving customer data in the message, then download it to the weather, and replace the message of the weather, which continue to be sent to the stream analytics.

I do not think this is possible. You are processing messages using an `EventProcessor`. That's the end of line when it comes to the event stream. From here you can do something with the data like persisting it or whatever but you cannot alter/overwrite the events and then somehow magically put them back in the same event hub stream.

It would be nearly impossible to implement because how could you deal when multiple consumers are reading the stream using different Consumer Groups, and what to do if those consumers are at other positions in the stream?

You have some options though:

1. In the `Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)` loop all messages like you do now and send them to another event hub which is then in turn connected to a Stream Analytics Job.
2. Using the `Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)` loop all messages like you do now, get the weather data and store that to Azure Blob Storage.

If you go explore option 2 you can connect the blob container as an input to the Stream Analytics Job.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have another problem. I would like to take advantage of shipping data to another eventhub, but the following code does not work.